# ASP.NET MVC - Rota não passa valores para o Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Criei uma nova Controller com nome `Conteudo`. Depois criei uma Action nela chamada de `conteudo` e adicionei uma nova View chamada de `Conteudo`. Antes era `PaginaBase` e a Controller de `Home`. Bem, copiei o conteudo da antiga View(`PaginaBase`) para essa nova View(`Conteudo`) e quando eu dou um View in browser, dá erro de Page not found(404). Na Url fica assim: ../Conteudo/Conteudo.

A minha rota está assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "RotaConteudo",
   url: "Conteudo/{Parametro}/{tipo}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Conteudo", action = "Conteudo", Parametro = "", tipo = "" }
);
```

Ok, é o seguinte. Criei uma nova view e um novo controller. Dentro do controller, criei uma action(ActionResult). Criei uma nova view e apontei para essa controller. Essa Action, recebe dois parametros, conforme fiz na Rota. O que passa é não está funcionando nada. Não dá erro, mas também não funciona. Tentando resolver agora, troquei os parametros de int para string, com direito fiz view in browser e dessa forma consegui visualizar a view. Mas pela aplicação não. Coloquei um break na Action e não para. Não faz nada e nem funciona. Ou seja, minha controller não está funcionando.

Minha action:

```
public ActionResult Conteudo(string nome, int Parametro, int tipo)
{
    AgaxturCmsEntities db = new AgaxturCmsEntities();

    int _parametro = Parametro;

    try
    {
        switch (tipo)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    var resultado = (from i in db.TB_INSTITUCIONAL
                                     join c in db.TB_INSTITUCIONAL_CATEGORIAS on i.Id_Categoria equals (c.id)
                                     where i.Ativo == 1 && c.Ativo == 1 && c.CdCliente == 1 && i.Id_Categoria == _parametro
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Conteudo = i.Conteudo
                                     }).FirstOrDefault();


                    ViewData["htmlBase"] = resultado.Conteudo;
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {

                    var menu_sup = (from rc in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR
                                    join c in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR_CATEGORIAS on rc.Id_Categoria equals (c.id)
                                    //join s in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR_SUBCATEGORIAS on rc.Id_SubCategoria equals (s.id)
                                    //join s2 in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR_SUBCATEGORIAS2 on rc.Id_SubCategoria2 equals (s2.id)
                                    where rc.Ativo == 1 && rc.Cdcliente == 1 && rc.Id_Categoria == _parametro
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Conteudo = rc.Conteudo

                                    }).FirstOrDefault();

                    ViewData["htmlBase"] = menu_sup.Conteudo;
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    var menu_sup = (from rc in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR
                                    join s in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR_SUBCATEGORIAS on rc.Id_SubCategoria equals (s.id)
                                    join s2 in db.TB_MENUSUPERIOR_SUBCATEGORIAS2 on rc.Id_SubCategoria2 equals (s2.id)
                                    where rc.Ativo == 1 && rc.Cdcliente == 1 && rc.Id_SubCategoria2 == _parametro
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Conteudo = rc.Conteudo

                                    }).FirstOrDefault();

                    ViewData["htmlBase"] = menu_sup.Conteudo;
                    break;
                }
        }
        return View("Conteudo");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string e = ex.Message;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Minha jquery

```
function MontaMenuInferior() {

    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Conteudo/MontaMenuInferior',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.resultado).each(function () {

                str = str + '<ul class="grid_4">' +
                                    '<li>' + this.SubCategoria + '</li>';


                $(this.subconsulta).each(function () {

                    if (this.Id_SubCategoria2 != null)

                        str = str + '<li><a href="/Conteudo/' + 'teste-de-nome/' + this.Id_SubCategoria2 + '/3" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';
                        //str = str + '<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("PaginaBase",new{ Parametro = 6, tipo = 3} )">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>'
                    else
                        str = str + '<li><a href="#' + this.SubCategoria2 + '" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';

                });

                str = str + '</ul>';

                $('#menufooter').append(str);

                str = "";

            });
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem confusa, você pode melhorá-la?

Comment: Ok, é o seguinte. Criei uma nova view e um novo controller. Dentro do controller, criei uma action(ActionResult). Criei uma nova view e apontei para essa controller. Essa Action, recebe dois parametros, conforme fiz na Rota. O que passa é não está funcionando nada. Não dá erro, mas também não funciona. Tentando resolver agora, troquei os parametros de int para string, com direito fiz view in browser e dessa forma consegui visualizar a view. Mas pela aplicação não. Coloquei um break na Action e não para. Não faz nada e nem funciona.

Comment: Atualize na sua pergunta.

Comment: Postei minha action e minha função js, para ver se há alguma coisa que faltou. No meu cshtml(View), eu apontei para o js Conteudo.js.

Comment: Creio que meu problema seja o seguinte, depois de pensar bastante. Tenho uma Index que monta o menu. Nesse menu é que eu devo chamar a Conteudo, passando os devidos parâmetros, para pegar o HTML correto do BD. Na index eu também aponto para o Conteudo.js. Não estou conseguindo fazer subir o menu, passando a rota. Coloquei um break tanto na Controller quanto na .js e não consigo debugar, não para no break. Eu não consigo ser muito claro na minha dúvida, por falta de entendimento da coisa toda.

Comment: O que você quis dizer para a rota que você iria fazer, nesta parte ?  { Parametro = "", tipo = "" }

Answer (score 2):

A opção *View in browser...* do Visual Studio, é meio que incompatível com o ASP.NET MVC, pois ele tenta navegar para a página com uma URL usando a estrutura de pastas como molde, ao invés de usar a rota para a página que foi definida via código.

Para visualizar a página corretamente, você deve executar a aplicação e colocar a URL desejada no navegador, sem esperar que o Visual Studio faça isso para você.

Comment: Isso eu faço. E pior, pela aplicação não funciona, conforme falei anteriormente. Não entra. Agora, se eu criar na pasta Home, aí funciona, mas preciso criar folders diferente para melhor organizar.

Comment: Você alterou o nome da classe? Digo, de HomeController para ConteudoController?

Comment: Criei outra. A home continua e fiz uma outra para Conteudo. É nesse momento que a coisa não anda. Nessa estrutura. Folder Controller tem duas controllers. Home e Conteudo. Na pasta View tem dois folders. Um chamado Home, com a view Index e outro folder chamado Conteudo com a view conteudo. A Controller Conteudo, que possui os métodos para carregar o Menu e montar a URL da nova página, não sobe nem a pau.

Comment: Tenta isolar o problema e postar o código do problema isolado. No seu exemplo tem um monte de chamadas ao banco de dados, e isso não tem relação com o problema, de forma que seja possível reproduzir o problema... assim ficaria mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Bem, para eu ter uma URL composta com o nome Conteudo, preciso ter uma Controller chamada conteudo e claro, dentro de uma pasta Chamada conteudo. Acontece, que eu criei essa controle e apontei para uma view de mesmo nome. Só que eu não consigo fazer isso funcionar. Não funciona. Se eu coloco na Home funciona, mas se eu coloco na Conteudo não funciona. Com funciona o site. A index, sobe e monta um menu, aliás dois, superior e inferior. Continua no próximo comentário

Comment: Ao montar esse menu, há uns submenus que apontam para um link dinâmico. É esse link que eu preciso montar assim: www.meudominio.com.br/Conteudo/nome-da-pagina-para-o-goofgle-achar/parametro2/parametro3(O nome da página é um parametro também). É exatamente isso que eu não consigo fazer. Essa é a rota para tudo isso.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi o que você quis fazer nesta parte !

```
defaults: new { controller = "Conteudo", action = "Conteudo", Parametro = "", tipo = " }
```

Tente algo assim:

```
{ controller = "Conteudo", action = "Conteudo", Parametro = UrlParameter.Optional, tipo = UrlParameter.Optional }
```